Limpiar los metadatos de los ficheros con php
Básicamente me gustaría limpiar los metadato que pudieran contener los ficheros que suban los usuarios de una aplicación antes de guardarlos.
He estado mirando y para las imágenes veo que PHP tiene la clase imagick para imágenes:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php
Para el resto ficheros (PDF, docx...) nativamente de PHP no encuentro nada.
Veo en packagist que lo que hay está basado en exiftool (creado en perla)
https://packagist.org/?query=exiftool
Mi pregunta es:
¿Habría alguna forma de hacer esta limpieza de metadatos de alguna manera "más nativa" en PHP?
¿A nivel de symfony habría algún componente?
Gracias.

Los "metadatos" son específicos del formato de archivo que estés procesando. Para el caso de imágenes será la información de ubicación y fecha o similar, el PDF tendrá lo suyo y así. ¿Qué tipos de archivos necesitas procesar exactamente?

Pues sería imágenes (JPEG, PNG,..., ), PDF, docx. Y no sé qué otros ficheros podrían tener metadatos sensibles
